# In WPF is it possible to bind to a property of a property in my DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I need to bind a TextBox's Text to a property of a class that itself a property of my DataContext.  So, for example if I have a class called ServerInstance and it has a string property called Name.  I expose a ServerInstance as a property called SelectedInstance in my code behind (viewmodel in this case).  My question is how can I bind a TextBox to the Name property of the SelectedInstance property?

Here is my ViewModel/Code behind:

```
public class ViewModel : Notifier
{
    private MobileServerInstance m_instance = null;
    private RelayCommand m_addCommand = null;
    private RelayCommand m_clearCommand = null;

    public MobileServerInstance ServerInstance
    {
        get { return m_instance; }
        set { m_instance = value; OnPropertyChanged("ServerInstance"); }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_addCommand == null)
            {
                m_addCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter=>Add(parameter), parameter=>CanAdd(parameter));
            }

            return m_addCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand ClearCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_clearCommand == null)
            {
                m_clearCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter => Clear(parameter), parameter => CanClear(parameter));
            }

            return m_clearCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool CanClear(object parameter)
    {
        return m_instance != null;
    }

    private void Clear(object parameter)
    {
        m_instance = null;
    }

    private bool CanAdd(object parameter)
    {
        return m_instance == null;
    }

    private void Add(object parameter)
    {
        m_instance = new MobileServerInstance();
    }
}
```

Notifier is a base class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and provides a protected OnPropertyChanged method which raises the PropertyChange event - typical pattern there.

Here is my simple class that I use for the DataContext:

```
public class MobileServerInstance : Notifier
{
    private string m_name = "Name";
    private string m_alias = "Alias";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_name; }
        set { m_name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public string Alias
    {
        get { return m_alias; }
        set { m_alias = value; OnPropertyChanged("Alias"); }
    }
}
```

And finally my xaml (this is a POC so the UI is very simple):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="500">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <src:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Name:" Margin="0 0 2 0" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0 0 8 0" Width="125" />
            <Button Margin="0 0 4 0" Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Width="75" />
            <Button Content="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" Width="75" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Margin="20 5 20 5"">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Width="40" Content="Name:" Margin="0 0 2 0" />
                <TextBox Width="250" Text="{Binding ServerInstance.Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 5 0 0">
                <Label Width="40" Content="Alias:" Margin="0 0 2 0" />
                <TextBox Width="250" Text="{Binding ServerInstance.Alias}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Thanks, in advance, for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{Binding Path=ServerInstance.Name}` must work, of course to see Name changing value even ServerInstance should be an `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly how I have it structured and my ServerInstance class does implement INotifyPropertyChanged (via the Notifier class which encapsulates that functionality).  My other UI elements that depend on that property for state work fine (the Add and Delete buttons) so I know the property is getting set and notifying the view.  The problem is when I type in the text box (and tab out so changes are reflected) my underlying ServerInstance does not get the changes in it's properties - they remain in their default state.

Comment: Furthermore, I've set breakpoints in the Setter/Getters of my ServerInstance properties and they are never hit so the underlying Binding engine is not actually calling those properties, despite my specifying the path (both with an explicit Path= and an implicit Path as is indicated in my xaml above.

Comment: Yes, using Path=ServerInstance.Name certainly does not work.  I am using VS2008, not sure if that matters, but it's not .Net 4.0 (3.51).  I'm working around it now with a very ugly solution.  I create properties that I then propagate to the m_instance.  This is ugly and I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I have to deliver today.  Thanks for taking the time to help :).

Comment: DOH!  I was setting the MEMBER variable when I called the AddCommand, not calling the setter so the view was never aware of a new ServerInstance (I raise the INotifyPropertyChanged event in the setter).  I changed my call in Add from m_serverInstance = new MobileServerInstance() to ServerInstance = new MobileServerInstance.  Thanks for pointing out the correct way, it was my stubborn brain that looked at that line of code twenty times and thought it was okay.

Comment: @SRM great, you find the bug !